# Bootstrap 4 col ordering causing bad cumulative layout shift score

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

Im using bootstrap 4.5 grid layout to make a 3 column website. I use a different order depending if its mobile or desktop view. Code is like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="es">
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha512-/DXTXr6nQodMUiq+IUJYCt2PPOUjrHJ9wFrqpJ3XkgPNOZVfMok7cRw6CSxyCQxXn6ozlESsSh1/sMCTF1rL/g==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2 mb-2">
          <p>First on mobile, second on desktop</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
          <p>second on mobile, first on desktop</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 order-md-3 mb-2">
          <p>third on mobile, third on desktop</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sadly Google pagespeed insights and lighthouse are giving me a high CLS score on Desktop only. I tried removing the order-md-X class and the CLS score goes down.
I dont really know what to do to have a better score and retain the col order.